# How can I programatically create a new view for Promoted Links using PnP Powershell?

Tags: pnp-powershell, promoted-links

I've got a Promoted Links list in SharePoint 2016 on premise with an additional custom field 'Category' (type: Text) added to it.

I want to make additional view that filter the Tiles based on this Category field.

Currently I use SharePoint Designer to manually create new Tiles views for SharePoint lists of type 'Promoted Links'.

This works, but I would like to automate this using PnP Powershell

This should be possible using Add-PnPView, but I haven't yet been able to find the correct parameters for this.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands work:

```
$caml = '
<Where>
<Eq>
 <FieldRef Name="Category"/>
 <Value Type="Text">MyCategory</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
'
$result = add-pnpview -List Links -Title "MyCategoryView" -Query $caml -ViewType Html  -fields Title, BackgroundImageLocation, Description, LinkLocation, LaunchBehavior, BackgroundImageClusterX, BackgroundImageClusterY, Category -RowLimit 30
```